# VSFlexGrid 7.0 ScrollBar Issue on Windows 7

Tags: c#, winforms, vb6, componentone, c1flexgrid

I am facing some issue with VSFlex grid 7.0. An Activex usercontrol that contains a vsflex grid is shown in winform application.

The scrollbar of vsflex grid are visible but not scrollable (looks like disabled).

This issue only happens when running on Windows 7 but it seems to be working fine on Windows XP.

Also on some flexgrid the scrollbar is scrollable but it returns back to it’s position again.

One weird behavior i found ->

When the form loads and suddenly i click on scrollbar (in less that a second time) and drag it, it scrolls without any problem.
And then i release the scrollbar, it stucks again and does not scroll then.

The same behavior is on many screens.

Are there any known issues with VSFlex grid or events we handle like MouseDown, MouseMove etc.

Sorry, I dont have any samples for the same.

Any thoughts are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

VsFlexgrid 7.0 is not supported on Windows 7 (VsFlex was marked obsolete long before Win7 was released). There might be some issues due to this. Also, it is an obsolete version of VsFlex. Use latest version of VsFlex 8.0 on Win7.

Thanks,
Richa